# Get region and set region from quote not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote

I'm using getRegion() and setRegion() but in my **quote** isn't saving values from setRegion(). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried using the debugger, debugger helps a lot in fining problems

Comment: I use logger because my debbuger isn't working. can you give any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand that Magento has few methods and fields for region.

If selected country is has list of regions you need to update `region_id`. Use `$address->setRegionId()`

If selected country doesn't you need to update `region`. Use `$address->setRegion()`

Also Magento supports the methods `setRegionCode` and `getRegionCode` which are related to region data.

You can find defined regions data in `directory_country_region` table.

Magento has a logic to update `region` value before save quote address when passed valid `region_id`